# Why use select(), when we have poll() and epoll()

Tags: c, sockets, posix-select

I looked at the differences between `poll`, `epoll` and `select`. What I don't understand is when should I use `select`. I don't see any advantage, given that `poll` and `epoll` have everything that `select` has, and more.

Comment: `epoll()` is Linux specific. So if you care for portablility, only `select()` and `poll()` remain.

Comment: Depends on the number of sockets (FD) you want to monitor. For less than 10 `select` is somehow faster than epoll. Also `epoll` is Unix specific. `select` has a MAX_LIMIT (1024 I think) whereas `epoll` doesn't have.

Comment: This is a great summary [poll vs select vs event-based ](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/poll-vs-select.html) and this is pretty good too [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html). `select` and is the most portable, `poll` next and `epoll` is linux only. Using `select` and `poll` is simpler than `epoll` but if need the scalability then go w/ `epoll` if you can.

Comment: Should look up and read Beej's guide to networking... it explains it all in a very useful manner.

Comment: You need to remember that `select()` preceded `poll()` by quite a number of years.

Answer (score 1):

Historically, `select` came first in BSD4.2 by 1983. Being first, it has the privilege of being the most prevalent and the most portable.

That said, both `select` and `poll` scales terribly. `select` scales to `O(highest_fd)`, and `poll` to `O(total_fds)`, according to `LIBEV(3)`. `epoll` scales much better for a large number of file descriptors, but is specific only to Linux.

Using an event library like `libevent`, `libev`, or `libuv` will provide an abstraction layer and try to use the most performant method on your system, so you shouldn't have to worry about choosing between `select`, `poll`, `epoll`, or `kqueue` (for MacOS and the BSD's).

Comment: 1984 would be closer, but it was certainly before that, and BSD 4.2, not 4.4.

Comment: @user207421 right, I was thinking of the select() that modern Linux conforms to. I updated the answer to mention both.

Comment: So it came first in both 4.2 *and* 4.4? in both 1982 and 1994? And what is 'the `select()` that modern Linux confirms to` if not `select()` from BSD 4.2?

Comment: @user207421 `man select(2)` reads: select()  conforms to ... 4.4BSD (select() first appeared in 4.2BSD).

Comment: So it appeared in 1982, and Linux conforms to that. It didn't change between 4.2 and 4.4.

Comment: @user207421 Ahh, I see. I fixed the historical error. I misinterpreted it mentioning BSD4.4 that it changed between the two versions.

Answer (score -2):

select() monitor less file descriptor than poll().
Moreover, some implementation of select() are just using poll().